# how do i get to show the repeating event details on all following dates in python django

Tags: python, django

Event Name : Guest Booking
Event State date : 1-feb-2022 and event ends on 5-feb-2022.
Contact person : ABC
Contact number : 12345

When I create this event on 1st of feb and end date will select as 5th of feb, my challenge is, created event should display event name, event date, contact person name and contact number till 5th of feb automatically, without me creating same for 2nd of feb, 3rd of feb till 5th of feb manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
import pprint
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    "event_name": "Guest Booking Event State",
    "from": datetime(2022, 2, 1),
    "to": datetime(2022, 2, 5),
    "contact_person": "ABC Contact",
    "contact_number": "12345",
}
duration = int((data["to"] - data["from"]).days) + 1

for i in range(duration):
    pprint.pprint(data)
```